# Why are smartphones getting so big?

Tags: usability, smartphone

It seems there is now a global trend among smartphone manufacturers, which is to make them bigger, over and over.
It reached a point where they have to make "mini" phones which often are low-end knock-off of the flagship.

Is there a logical design-related explanation ? Are people's hands getting bigger (mine certainly aren't) ?

Comment: Lately, content is king and bigger display basically equals more things to see. No matter how many pixels you have in a 2" screen, it will be no match to a 720p 4" screen in terms of content presentation, especially because screen real estate is not measured in pixels, but in actual physical length. Basically, people want to have a mobile TV

Comment: There are 2 big points for me, more ux than design:
gaming and office
watch the apple presentation: http://www.apple.com/live/2014-sept-event/

Answer (score 2):

**It's a trend.**

One company does it, two companies do it. Two companies do it, four companies do it. Etc.

Tim Cook said they wouldn't make a bigger phone but now with the iPhone 6 Plus, they have. Why? Because other companies have done it too. And as a company you sometimes have to go with market demand: users want it, so they have to make it.

Users switched, because if they wanted a bigger screen, they had to switch to e.g. a Samsung Galaxy.

**Phones/tablets are becoming our PC.**

No matter if you're working, sending some emails, browsing on Facebook... phones and tablets are taking over these tasks from the PC. Therefore, a bigger screen is required. You have to admit, sending documents on a 3.5" inch screen isn't that comfortable, right? ;)

**They're still compact.**

This trend is probably nowhere near it's end, because the devices are still compact.